# Node.js variables being changed without any operations performed on them

Tags: node.js

I am using a node.js server for a multiplayer synchronized dice, but i am having some strange problems with variables changing that are not referenced or used...

```
    var origonalRolls = rolls;

    //identify epic fails
    var epicFails = [];
    for(var r = 0; r < rolls.length; r++)
        if(rolls[r] === 1)
            epicFails.push(r);

    console.log("TEST 1 :: " + JSON.stringify(rolls));
    console.log("TEST 2 :: " + JSON.stringify(origonalRolls));
    //remove epic fails and the corresponding heighest
    if(epicFails.length > 0){
        for(var i = epicFails.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
            rolls.splice(epicFails[i], 1);
            if(rolls[rolls.length-1] >= success)
                rolls.splice(rolls.length-1, 1);
        }
    }
    console.log("TEST 3 :: " + JSON.stringify(rolls));
    console.log("TEST 4 :: " + JSON.stringify(origonalRolls));
```

the above should find any element in the `rolls` array which is 1 and then add it to `epicFails`. it should then remove it from `rolls` as well as the heighest remaining roll. (note, `rolls` is sorted numerically)

for some reason the output of this segment of code is as follows:

```
TEST 1 :: [1,1,2,3,3,6,7,7,9,9]
TEST 2 :: [1,1,2,3,3,6,7,7,9,9]
TEST 3 :: [2,3,3,6,7,7]
TEST 4 :: [2,3,3,6,7,7]
```

I am unsure why `rolls` and `origonalRolls` start the same and end the same. I am only using `rolls`.

Any help and/or explanation to this problem is welcome, it's been troubling me for a long time now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript Arrays and Objects are only shallow copied - which means that an array (rolls) copied from another array (originalRolls) is only a reference to originalRolls - it is not an entirely new array, and modifying values in one will affect values in the other.

You will need to implement a deep copy function to create an entirely new array based off another. There are numerous imlementations of deep copying arrays/objects both here and elsewhere on the net - [here is one of them](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/deep-copying-of-objects-and-arrays/) from a quick Google.

Comment: Fascinating, i had no idea. I'm rather amazed i have made it this far with js and not encountered such problems. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `var origonalRolls = rolls;` with:

```
var origonalRolls = [];
for (var i = 0, len = rolls.length; i < len; i++) {
    origonalRolls[i] = rolls[i];
}
```

Comment: It's much easier to do `var originalRolls = rolls.slice(0);`.